# Why does my generator function turned into a non-iterable float object?

Tags: python, generator, python-decorators

Greetings everyone hope you're having a good day. I want to measure the time it took for my system to run a [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Sequence_properties) generator using a my own-built `performance` decorator with `num` as the index of the sequence. My question is, I still don't understand how and why my `fib` generator function seemingly converted into a float. And how can I make this work? I attached my code, my output, and my expected output. This is my first stackoverflow question, so pardon me if I didn't do this properly.

Thanks beforehand.

Code:

```
from time import time
    
def performance(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time()
        result = t2-t1
        print(f'It took {t2-t1} s')
        return result
    return wrapper

@performance
def fib(number):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for item in range(number):
        yield a
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp + a

for item in fib(20):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
    for item in fib(20):
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Expected Output:

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
It took xxx s.
```

Comment: It's because your wrapper function returns `t2-t1`, which is a float. You want to return the result of calling `func()` instead.

Comment: That's why you're supposed to first reduce your code to a [mcve]. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked. What I realized was, that I should've returned the `func` not the `t2-t1`, which was a float, in the decorator (credit to [@Tim Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2705542/tim-peters)).

I also realized that to measure the duration using the `performance` decorator, I could make a new function `printfib` dedicated for printing the Fibbonaci sequence. Somehow, using the decorator on the `fib` generator doesn't work. Perhaps it's because the generator returns or `yield` a single number every single time it's iterated, and I reckon that what I want to know is how long the whole loop was going, rather than only a single iteration.
Thanks everyone.

```
from time import time

def performance(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time()
        print(f'It took {t2-t1} s')
        return result
    return wrapper


def fib(number):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for item in range(number):
        yield a
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp + a

@performance
def printfib(num):
    for item in fib(num):
        print(item)
    return ('Done printing Fibbonaci numbers.')

print(printfib(20))
```